# error in webscraping by python with selenium library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I tried to extract data the site below with selenium library but Unfortunately I got next error. is there anyone who can help me??

from selenium import webdriver

```
url = 'https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-011'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data')

for table1 in table:
    value = table1.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]').text
    quantity = table1.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]').text
    unit = table1.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]').text
    print(value, quantity, quantity)
```

the Error is:

```
enter image description herePS C:\Users\asus\Desktop\home> [840:7000:0417/201023.654:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:10:23.656] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[840:7000:0417/201023.654:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:10:23.658] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[840:7000:0417/201023.654:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:10:23.659] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[840:7000:0417/201023.659:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [20:10:23.660] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[840:16136:0417/201113.924:ERROR:util.cc(126)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create the directory manually:
"**C:\Program Files\Google\GoogleUpdater**".
Should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should link to your webDriver using its path if you haven't already

> driver = webdriver.Chrome("your WebDriver Path")

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work with the path.

Comment: have you installed chrome webdriver

Comment: does chrome launch when you run the Python file